# Событие на прокрутку в Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Перемещение шапки до меня сделали через скрипт. В ИЕ при скролле происходит сначала сам скролл, а потом он понимает, что есть еще событие, дай-ка я выполню и событие, которое на скролл повешено. Проиcходит скачок шапки. Она сначала уходит по скроллу, а потом прыгает на прежнее место. В других браузерах сначала выполняется скрипт и все хорошо.

Некорректный скролл проиходит при вращении колеса мыши и при нажатии на стрелку скроллбара. При зажатии и протяжке полосы прокрутки работает корректно.

Можно ли как-то заблокировать события на колесико и на стрелку скроллбара и написать собственный обработчик на них?

На колесо мыши событие я уже нашел  - mousewheel. `position:fixed` не предлагать, фиксировать нужно не только шапку, да еще в двух направлениях разные элементы

P.S. Оказывается, что при большой странице тупит даже при зажатии и протяжке полосы прокрутки. Поэтому требуется вообще заблокировать скролл

ППС: 
Вот так выглядит обработчик скролла:

```
 var scrollHandler = function (scrollTop, scrollLeft) {
            for(k = 0, len = cs.length; k < len; k += 1) {
                cs[k].style.top = scrollTop + 'px';
            };
            for(i = 0, n = firstColCells.length; i < n; i += 1) {
                firstColCells[i].style.left = scrollLeft + 'px';
            };
        };
```

массивы - элементы шапки и столбцов, которые нужно фиксировать
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

на картинке изображена структура таблицы, где 0 - ячейка всегда на одном месте. А черточки - направления, в которых эти ячейки могут перемещаться.
То есть часть шапки всегда неподвижна, а в другой части может быть очень много столбцов, которые будут прокручиваться по горизонтали. Надеюсь понятно изъяснился

cs - ячейки всей шапки, firstColCells - ячейки нескольких первых столбцов, которые фиксированы при горизонтальном скролле

Answer (score 1):

Без кода я многого сказать не смогу...

---

Можно к примеру поставить костыль для IE, чтобы код не выполнялся

```
$(document).on('scroll', function (evt) {
    if (isIE) {
       evt.preventDefault();
       return false;
    }
    ...
 });
```

Других вариантов пока нет, т.к. в слепую пытаться решить проблему глупо

Comment: решение не работает, как только не пытался его прилепить. Мне кажется я нашел ответ в документации msdn.microsoft.com. IE всегда сначала делает, а потом думает. То есть как-то предотвратить скролл нельзя в принципе

Comment: Я не раз делал кроссбраузерные фичи со скроллом и в IE 9+ было всё хорошо с этим. Так что я склоняюсь в сторону того, что в скрипте используются не совсем правильные способы прокрутки Вашей шапки.

Comment: Идеей попытаюсь воспользоваться, может что-то получится

Comment: добавил код обработчика, может что посоветуете?

Comment: вот мне с первого взгляда не совсем понятно как эта шапка у вас работает... Скиньте, пожалуйста еще структуру и переменные cs. Вообще похоже что шапка состоит из отдельных элементов и вы каждый по очереди перебираете и меняете координаты. Вот пока не увижу структуру мне не понятна такая логика.